# Changing a sql server query to sqlite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I'm converting a Sql Server query to sqlite and I am in the process of learning the SQLite queries.  Regardless this is the one area that I am having a hard time with and that is the dates.

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, tblSomeTable.EventDate)) >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

What would the equivalent to this in sqlite be?  Thank you in advance.

The Event date field is a accepted datetime format - "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"

Comment: This just compares both date without the time part or with the time set to `00:00:000`.

Comment: Are you sure this even works in SQL Server because I see that the last parameter to `DATEADD` in your code is an integer, whereas, it should be a DATE type value?

Comment: Yes I am sure it works in SQL Server

Comment: Yes it would work. Shorter would be casting to date() datatype and compare like:  Select cast(eventDate as Date) >= cast( getdate() as Date)

In SQLite it is much shorter as already answered ( Date(EventDate) >= Date() )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime is stored as TEXT in SQLite, so you can just compare strings:

```
CREATE TABLE tblSomeTable (EventDate TEXT);
INSERT INTO tblSomeTable (EventDate) VALUES
    (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now', '-1 day')),
    (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now'          )),
    (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now', '+1 day'));

SELECT EventDate,
       substr(EventDate, 1, 10),
       strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now'),
       substr(EventDate, 1, 10) >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
FROM tblSomeTable;

SELECT EventDate,
       substr(EventDate, 1, 10),
       date(),
       substr(EventDate, 1, 10) >= date()
FROM tblSomeTable;
```

The result in both cases *(at the date of this edit :-)* would be:

```
2016-01-14 12:34:56.789|2016-01-14|2016-01-15|0
2016-01-15 12:34:56.789|2016-01-15|2016-01-15|1
2016-01-16 12:34:56.789|2016-01-16|2016-01-15|1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the values in your table are stored in one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), you can use the [`date` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to extract the date part of a timestamp:

```
date(tblSomeTable.EventDate) >= date('now')
```

Comment: The eventdate column is an actual datetime column.  So is this supposed to replace the entire query I posted?

Comment: I ran this in my query and I returned no results.  The datatype for that column is datetime.  I do return results on the Sql Server column

Comment: The column's data type does not matter; what counts is the format of the values stored in the column.

Comment: The query that you posted doesn't work I should say.

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/56395/1/0). How is your DB different from the SQL Fiddle?

Comment: It is the same but on the sql server query I return four results but with this I am returning one result.

Comment: Take a look I posted the entire query I am using.

Comment: I don't know your data.

Comment: This answer is correct - I came up with exactly the same thing independently (posted an answer, realised it was the same and then deleted it.)

Comment: Same here. I was about to post `date(tblSomeTable.EventDate) >= date()` as the answer. The original SQL query is just getting rid of hours in datetime values and comparing the net days to today's date. If it's not working, something must be wrong with the EventDate data.

Comment: Actually not.  Data format that is in that column is fine.

Comment: Also I need to to strip the time out of the query and just compare dates.

Comment: @HisnamewasRobertPaulson But the time *is* being stripped out of the query - see the second and third columns here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e6e75/3.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would say is that you shouldn't use that predicate in SQL Server, because enclosing columns in expression prevent SQL Server from use any index. If that predicate is the only one in the where clause then SQL Server would scan the entire table.

However the predicate can be rewritten in the following way:

```
tblSomeTable.EventDate >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
AND tblSomeTable.EventDate < DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

In this way, if there is an index on EventDate column, SQL Server would use it if it covers the query or if it is selective enough.

The same rule is applicable to SQLite.

Assuming EventDate is stored as ISO8601 string. The predicate can be written for SQLite like this:

```
EventDate LIKE date('now') || '%'
```

If there is an index on EventDate column, SQLite can use it.

How are your dates stored in SQLite? Could you post how [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) show them?

EDIT:

Oh! Sorry! I realized I miss the `>` part of `>=`. I saw `=` instead of `>=`. My answer were correct if the the operator was `=`.  For `>=` my answer should be:

```
tblSomeTable.EventDate >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

For SQL Server. And:

```
EventDate >= date('now')
```

For SQLite.

I'm getting older, sorry.

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain why this answer is downvoted. I believe I'm absolutely right. So please, give some light to my ignorance

Comment: IMHO downvoter is a stupid, downvoting w/o any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite3 does not have a date type for its Datatype list. Referencing [the sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) shows that sqlite has a few functions to manipulate times. I would imagine just converting to unix time as an integer would be your best bet.

Edit. I would suggest an actual query to replace but I'm not nearly as familiar with sql as I am sqlite.

Comment: I'm on the opposite end where I am familiar with sql but no with SQLite.  lol.

Comment: Also I'm using datetime not date

Answer (score -1):

I believe CL has already answered correctly. Might it be you stored the values as seconds since epoch (ie: Skype stores its datetime values like that in an SQLite table < g >).

```
SELECT * from SomeTable 
  where date(eventdate, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') >= date()
```